# Why can't I connect to the influx shell?

Tags: influxdb

After installing influxdb, the ui screen works well.

In the example(my environments ubuntu 18.04), if you enter './influx', you are connected to the

influx shell, but the following appears.

````
Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -precision

NAME:
   influx - Influx Client

USAGE:
   influx [command]

COMMANDS:
   version              Print the influx CLI version
   write                Write points to InfluxDB
   bucket               Bucket management commands
   completion           Generates completion scripts
   query                Execute a Flux query
   config               Config management commands
   org, organization    Organization management commands
   delete               Delete points from InfluxDB
   user                 User management commands
   task                 Task management commands
   telegrafs            List Telegraf configuration(s). Subcommands manage Telegraf configurations.
   dashboards           List Dashboard(s).
   export               Export existing resources as a template
   secret               Secret management commands
   v1                   InfluxDB v1 management commands
   auth, authorization  Authorization management commands
   apply                Apply a template to manage resources
   stacks               List stack(s) and associated templates. Subcommands manage stacks.
   template             Summarize the provided template
   bucket-schema        Bucket schema management commands
   ping                 Check the InfluxDB /health endpoint
   setup                Setup instance with initial user, org, bucket
   backup               Backup database
   restore              Restores a backup directory to InfluxDB
   remote               Remote connection management commands
   replication          Replication stream management commands
   server-config        Display server config
   help, h              Shows a list of commands or help for one command

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
   --help, -h  show help
Error: flag provided but not defined: -precision```

Could it be because the version(1.xx -> 2.xx) is different? Or is there another way?
````

Comment: HINT: If you are looking for the InfluxQL shell from 1.x, run "influx v1 shell"

Answer (score 0):

influxdb 1.x and 2.x is very different. 1.x used database and 2.x used bucket. so It's different to use influx cli.